# Eclipse RCP activeWhen expression with static class

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

So i have a class like this:

```
public class A {
   ...
   public static class B {
      ...
   }
}
```

And i have a handler in my rcp application defined like this:

```
<extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
      <handler
            class="HandlerClass"
            commandId="commandId">
         <activeWhen>
            <with
                  variable="selection">
               <iterate
                     ifEmpty="false">
                  <instanceof
                        value="A.B">
                  </instanceof>
               </iterate>
               <count
                     value="1">
               </count>
            </with>
         </activeWhen>
      </handler>
</extension>
```

The instanceof part doesnt work. What i want to do is to check if the items in the selection variable are of type B. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Property Testers, to check programmatically if a handler is active.

Check this blog entry: [Me, myself and Property Testers](https://www.compeople.eu/blog/?p=704)